# Does a Markdown parser exist that can also generate Markdown in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, generator, markdown

I want to parse a Markdown document so I get a tree structure that I am able to manipulate.  Afterwards I want the output to be Markdown again.

Example:

```
# This is a title

And a short paragraph...
```

- m = SomeLib.parse("# This is a tit...")
- m.insert(1, "Here is a new paragraph") # or something simmilar
- m.to_md

Should become

```
# This is a title

Here is a new paragraph

And a short paragraph...
```

As I want to heavily change the document I do not want to use REGEX or simillar techniques.

I looked into Maruku and BlueCloth but somehow I cannot generate Markdown again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not out of the box, but using [redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) you could write a custom renderer to build your tree and then manipulate it.

Though beware in this case you can't reuse the Markdown and Renderer instance and all methods in the custom Renderer subclass are supposed to return a string. Something like this could be a starting point:

```
class StackRenderer < Redcarpet::Render::Base
  attr_reader :items

  def initialize
    super
    @items = []
  end

  def header(title, level)
    items << { :text => title, :level => level, :type => :header }
    "#{'#' * level} #{title}\n\n"
  end

  def paragraph(text)
    items << { :text => text, :type => :paragraph }
    "#{text}\n\n"
  end
end

# example...
sr = StackRenderer.new
md = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(sr)

text = <<-EOF
# This is a title

And a short paragraph...
EOF

md.render(text) # => "# This is a title\n\nAnd a short paragraph...\n\n"

sr.items # => [{:type=>:header, :level=>1, :text=>"This is a title"},
         #     {:type=>:paragraph, :text=>"And a short paragraph..."}]
```